# Run severel scripts from a folder one after another

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote 50 shell scripts named `00abc.sh`, `00bcd.sh`, `00cde.sh`, `01def.sh`, `02efg.sh`, ..., `09xyz.sh`. The higher the number, the higher the priority. Every script is in the same folder.

How can I write a wrapper which runs each script one after another, beginning with the last script (`09xyz.sh`) and ending at the first (`00abc.sh`)? I don't want to hardcode the script names.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for f in `ls -1 |sort -rn` ; do
    if [ -x "$f" ];then
        $f
    fi
done
```

Comment: Added `-n` to sort for numeric order.

Comment: If you have subdirectories you will also need the `-d` check suggested by @mivk

Answer (score 0):

You can list all scripts in your folder with something like this, which checks that the file is executable, and that it is not a directory :

```
for f in *; do [ -x "$f" ] && [ ! -d "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done
```

You can `sort` the output, and use the `-r` option to reverse the sort order. So you could get a list of your scripts in the right order with

```
for f in *; do [ -x "$f" ] && [ ! -d "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done | sort -r
```

To actually run the found scripts, you can use `eval` :

```
for f in *; do [ -x "$f" ] && [ ! -d "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done | sort -r | while read runit; do ./$runit; done
```

(Add `echo` before `./$runit` to check first what would be run)

Comment: This does not run the script in the correct sequence but only sorts the output after executing the script in the wrong sequence

Comment: Even then, this does not sort the output according to execution sequence but reversed alphabetically. So it is possible that the sorted output contain output from script 5 then script 1 then script 3 then script 1 then script 10 then script 5 etc.

Comment: You can add `-n` to sort numerically. But according to your example with 0-padded numbers at the start of the file name, it is not necessary. In this case alphabetic and numeric sorting should be exactly the same.

Comment: No, you don't understand. You are sorting the **output** which is wrong. The OP wants to sort the **INPUT**

Comment: Say for example you have 3 scripts: 00.sh outputs numbers 1,2,3. Then 01.sh outputs numbers 2,4,6, then 03.sh outputs the numbers 3,6,9. The expected output is 3,6,9,2,4,6,1,2,3. Your solution would output 9,5,5,4,3,3,2,1 which is wrong